# Calling main menu is displaying sub menu

Tags: c, submenu

i am doing an airplain seat booking system. Here I have a main menu of chooseflight() and submenu of printmenu(). Whenever I press 'f' from printmenu's options I should return to mainmenu. But I cannot. Please help me!

```
int main()
{
    chooseflight(); 
    fflush(stdin);
    return 0;   
}

void chooseflight(void)
{
    char selectflight;
    printf("a) Flight 102 b) Flight 311 c) Flight 444 d) Flight 519 e)Quitprogram\n");
        scanf("%c",&selectflight);
        switch(selectflight)
        {
            case 'a':
             puts("Welcome to flight 102 service");
             while(1){
             printmenu102();
             }
             break;
             case 'b':
             puts("Welcome to flight 311 service");
             printmenu311();
             break;
             case 'c':
             puts("Welcome to flight 444 service");
             printmenu444();
             break;
             case 'd':
             puts("Welcome to flight 519 service");
             printmenu519();
             break;
             case 'e':
             Quitprogram();
             break;
        }
}

void printmenu102()
{
        char lablename;

    printf("a) Show number of empty seats b) Show list of empty seats c)Show alphabetical list of seats d) Assign a passenger toa seat e)Delete a seat assignment f) Quittotopmenu\n");

    scanf("%c",&lablename);
    switch(lablename)
    {
        case 'a':
            Noofemptyseats102();
            break;
            case 'b':
            Listofemptyseats102();
            break;
            case 'c':
            Alphabeticallistofseats102();
            break;
            case 'd':
            Assingseats102();
            break;
            case 'e':
            Deleteseats102();
            break;
            case 'f':
            Quittotopmenu();
            break;
    }
}

void Quitprogram(void)
 {
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 void Quittotopmenu(void)
 {
chooseflight();
 }
```

My output is:

```
a) Flight 102 b) Flight 311 c) Flight 444 d) Flight 519 e)Quitprogram

a

Welcome to flight 102 service

a) Show number of empty seats b) Show list of empty seats c)Show alphabetical list of seats d) Assign a passenger toa seat e)Delete a seat assignment f) Quittotopmenu

a) Show number of empty seats b) Show list of empty seats c)Show alphabetical list of seats d) Assign a passenger toa seat e)Delete a seat assignment f) Quittotopmenu

f

a) Flight 102 b) Flight 311 c) Flight 444 d) Flight 519 e)Quitprogram

a) Show number of empty seats b) Show list of empty seats c)Show alphabetical list of seats d) Assign a passenger toa seat e)Delete a seat assignment f) Quittotopmenu
```

The submenu is automatically being displayed without staying in main menu.

Comment: You probably need to `fflush(stdin);` after each `scanf` call and not just once in `main`.

Comment: Hello thanks for your time, but no luck! still the same thing cannot access main menu options, being redirected to sub menu options directly.

Comment: That's because `fflush` doesn't apply to `input` streams, it applies to `output` streams. See `man 3 fflush` **For  output streams**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked! I missed the while loop. My bad!

```
while(1)
        {
    printf("a) Flight 102 b) Flight 311 c) Flight 444 d) Flight 519 e)Quitprogram\n");
        scanf("%c",&selectflight);

        switch(selectflight)
        {
            case 'a':
             puts("Welcome to flight 102 service");
             while(1){
             printmenu102();
             }
             break;
             case 'b':
             puts("Welcome to flight 311 service");
             while(1){
             printmenu311();
             break;
             }
             case 'c':
             puts("Welcome to flight 444 service");
             while(1){
             printmenu444();
             }
             break;
             case 'd':
             puts("Welcome to flight 519 service");
             while(1){
             printmenu519();
             }
             break;
             case 'e':
             Quitprogram();
             break;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Try to avoid using scanf while parsing character or string inputs try for better options -- fgets ,sscanf etc.. happy coding !!

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps you with your problem:

```
int main() {
    //When somthing fails return 0
    //Else continue
    if ( !chooseflight() ) {
        return 0;
    }  
    fflush(stdin);
    return 0;   
}

void chooseflight(void) {

    char selectflight;

    printf("a) Flight 102 \
            b) Flight 311 \
            c) Flight 444 \
            d) Flight 519 \
            e)Quitprogram\n");

        scanf("%c",&selectflight);
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(selectflight) {
            case 'a':
             puts("Welcome to flight 102 service");

             //When somthing fails return 0
             //Else Return 1 Success
             if ( !printmenu102() ) {
                return 0;
             } else {
                return 1;
             }

             break;

             case 'b':
             puts("Welcome to flight 311 service");
             printmenu311();
             break;

             case 'c':
             puts("Welcome to flight 444 service");
             printmenu444();
             break;

             case 'd':
             puts("Welcome to flight 519 service");
             printmenu519();
             break;

             case 'e':
             Quitprogram();
             break;
        }
}

void printmenu102() {
        char lablename;

    printf("a) Show number of empty seats \
            b) Show list of empty seats \
            c)Show alphabetical list of seats \
            d) Assign a passenger toa seat \
            e)Delete a seat assignment \
            f) Quittotopmenu\n");

    scanf("%c",&lablename);
    fflush(stdin);

    switch(lablename) {
        case 'a':
            Noofemptyseats102();
            break;

            case 'b':
            Listofemptyseats102();
            break;

            case 'c':
            Alphabeticallistofseats102();
            break;

            case 'd':
            Assingseats102();
            break;

            case 'e':
            Deleteseats102();
            break;

            case 'f':
                //Success
                return 1;
            break;
    }
}

void Quitprogram(void)
 {
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 void Quittotopmenu(void)
 {
chooseflight();
 }
```

Comment: `main` just calls `chooseflight` so I don't see how this would change anything (other than by hitting the `fflush` after `chooseflight` returned.

Comment: Hi,@Rizier123 I tried that but still the same output. If I do not use the endless loop I am being exited from the program after that submenu appears.

Comment: @Rizier123 I want to go back because if one flight service is full I should give users an option to select from remaining 3 services